# Double segue tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have problem with double segue connections using tableview

When I click on a row to go on another table view goes like this:

```
tableView1  ->  tableView #2 -> again tableView #2
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @tsnorri When I click on a row to go on another table view goes like this

tableView1  ->  tableView #2 -> again tableView #2  Twice for the same tableView

Comment: Where is TableView 2 supposed to take you?

Comment: Seems like you have segue connection in the storyboard too, check it please

Comment: Are you using prepareForSegue?

Comment: @Siriss not using prepareForSegue

Comment: Try adding prepareForSegue, and log when it hits that segue. Also, in storyboard, do you have the segue hooked up to a cell, or is it from scene to scene?

Comment: @Siriss Yes I have segue identifier in storyboard

Comment: If you have a segue in the storyboard, performing it programmatically is a non-sense, chose : in the storyboard or from the code.

Comment: Don't use both didselectrow and prepare for segue. You are doing the same twice. Use prepareforsegue Only.

Answer (score 1):

you probably connected the segue in the storyboard to the tableViewCell. If you did so you don't have to call `performSegueWithIdentifier`

So the solution would be one of the following:

1) Connect the segue in the storyboard to the UITableViewController and not to the tableView or to the tableViewCell and then do `performSegueWithIdentifier`

2) Remove the call to `performSegueWithIdentifier`. If you want to send data, use `prepareForSegue` method to get the destination view controlelr and pass data to it. (You will have to save which cell was clicked in the `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`, to know what data to send)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"secondSeg" sender:indexPath];`. Alternatively, make the segue in Storyboard from your TableView #1 Scene to your TableView #2 Scene instead of from the cell to the scene, and implement `prepareForSegue`.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably made a connection between the storyboards or you have named with the same name the identifier

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"iAmtheIdentifier"]){
```